# Is the following map continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ and $C(Y,\mathbb{R})$ be the space of continuous functions with $X$ is compact metric space and $Y$ be closed subset of $X$. The spaces are using the supremum norm. Is the map $R:C(X)\to C(Y)$ with $Rf=f|_Y$ a continuous map?
If it is how do I show it, thank you.

Comment: $\|R(f)-R(g)\|\leq\|f-g\|$

Comment: @Ruy So since $Y\subseteq X$ where $X$ has bigger sup, it is Lipschitz, hence continuous, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is it.

Comment: @Ruy Thank you very much, if you wish, I can accept your answer if you would like to write below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ and $g$ are in $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ then
$$
  \|R(f)-R(g)\| = \sup_{y\in Y}|f(y)-g(y)| \leq $$$$\leq \sup_{x\in X}|f(x)-g(x)| =   \|f-g\|.
  $$
This shows that $R$ is Lipschitz, and hence continuous.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can manage to show that when $g: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map between compact metric spaces, then the application $C(Y, \mathbb{R}) \rightarrow C(X, \mathbb{R})$ obtained by precomposing by $g$ is continuous with your topology (sup norm). Then, your case follows with $g$ the inclusion $X \subset Y$.